# Getting error: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double'

Tags: c, printf

I don't know why this won't compile. Any idea?

It is pretty straight forward and I've spent forever looking at it and can't figure out what is wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void euroToDollar(double euro);

int main() {
    double europrice1 = 1.00;

    euroToDollar(europrice1);
    return 0;
}

void euroToDollar(double euro){

    double dollar = euro * 1.11;

    printf("EUR%.2d = USD%.2d" ,euro, dollar);
    return;
}
```

The error message:

```
Basic.c:24:39: error: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
  'double' [-Werror,-Wformat]
printf("EUR%.2d = USD%.2d" ,euro, dollar);
                     ~~~~         ^~~~~~
                     %.2f
 2 errors generated.
```

Comment: `printf("EUR%.2d = USD%.2d", euro, dollar);`

Comment: printf("EUR%.2d = USD%.2d", euro, dollar); missing comma after "

Comment: `printf("EUR%.2f = USD%.2f\n", euro, dollar);`

Comment: Getting an error message or a warning, you should read that very carefully and follow it. The message is more than clear here.

Comment: I suggest you to not use `-Werror` when you don't understand each warning yet. It can be a very frustrating experience to fix each warning, especially when some of them are incorrect

Comment: FUZxxl, I counter that with always have -Werror on for small programs if you are a beginner. How else would you learn?

Comment: @FUZxxl: That is exactly the wrong advise. Beginner or not, warnings are you friend. And beginners should read them very carefully and edit their code. Experienced users will just produce much less warnings on a first compile.

Comment: @kchoi You do learn from warnings but `-Werror` is a really frustrating experience, especially combined with `-Wextra -pedantic` as some people suggest. Many things warned by these are not wrong at all!

Comment: @Olaf, rockstar programmers compiles code successfully on the first try with -w. Then they fight the logic errors that warning would have shown.

Comment: @kchoi: I'll never become a rockstar programmer and proud about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, you need to change

```
printf("EUR%.2d = USD%.2d" euro, dollar);
```

to

```
printf("EUR%.2f = USD%.2f", euro, dollar);
```

Notice **two** changes

1. Added the `,`, as required by the [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) syntax.
2. `double` should be printed with `%f` format specifier. Using wrong type of argument invokes   [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I've updated the program and I get anew error. Ive updated it so that you can see it yourself

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. So floats and doubles both use %f as their format specifier?

Comment: @ÉananHalferty in case of `printf()`, a float value as argument is promoted to double. So, essentially, yes.

Comment: @ÉananHalferty on your post you've only updated the `,` and not the 2 `%.2d` to `%.2f` - are you sure you didn't forget?

Comment: @ÉananHalferty Yes, a `float` is promoted to `double` when passed through valist. Writing `%d` means that the value should be treated as a decimal integer. See `http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma.

```
printf("EUR%.2f = USD%.2f" euro, dollar);
```

Should be

```
printf("EUR%.2f = USD%.2f", euro, dollar);
```

Comment: now it says this: Basic.c:24:39: error: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'double' [-Werror,-Wformat]
    printf("EUR%.2d = USD%.2d" ,euro, dollar);
                         ~~~~         ^~~~~~
                         %.2f
2 errors generated.

Comment: @ÉananHalferty: Read about format string syntax. The message is clearly stating what is wrong. Just think about it. SO is no debugging service.

Comment: @Olaf I agree, but that does not invalidate the fact that this answer is incomplete. :-) Just saying.

Comment: Dear Lawrence sir, please update the post to make it complete. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I did not say otherwise :-)